# Parent / Child element bindings for click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the jQuery tablesorter - I've got checkboxes on each row and essentially want to have a "select all" checkbox inside the `<th>` element.

I can't actually access the click event, even after disabling the tablesorter on that specific column.

Simple JS test:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"].select-all').on("click", function(e){
  console.log("Clicked!");
});
```

Click event does nothing, which is why I'm presuming the tablesorter is binded to the parent `<th>` element. The header:

```
<tr>
  <th class="no-sort"><input type="checkbox" class="select-all" /></th>
  <th>Some Sortable title</th>
</tr>
```

Any ideas on how to access that child checkbox event? I have set that column to not sort via:

```
// Table-sort
var noSortHeaders = {};
$("table").find("th.no-sort").each( function(index, el){
  noSortHeaders[ $(this).index() ] = {sorter: false};
});
$("table").tablesorter({
    headers: noSortHeaders
});
```

Comment: Perhaps using event delegation would work? $("table").on("click",'input[type="checkbox"].select-all', function(evt) {} );

Comment: your code seems fine here https://jsfiddle.net/ammarcse/LvLytmch/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't include the jquery tablesorter, but delegation worked. Want to put that as the answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: @user2182349, see comment above

Comment: [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4226/) was made for my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html), but it should also work for the original. Note: The original tablesorter does not support multiple tbody sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the checkbox is created after `DOM ready` event, you do want to use event delegation. And I would prefer the `change` event to the `click` event:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox].select-all', function(e) {
    console.log('Changed!');
});
```

Or, better still:

```
$('table').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox].select-all', function(e) {
    console.log('Changed!');
});
```